# Como usar dos tablas en un mismo formulario django

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de utilizar un solo formulario para guardar dos tablas diferentes, entre ellas estan relacionadas con un OneToOneField, el cual tambien necesito que se asocien al momento de enviar el formulario

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import siloProperties, granos

class getSiloForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = siloProperties, granos
        fields = [
            'nombre',
            'kilogramos',
            'litros'
        ]
        labels = {
            'nombre' : 'Nombre del anuncio',
            'kilogramos' : 'Cantidad en Kg',
            'litros' : 'Cantidad en litros'
        }
```

Comment: has probado utulizar Form en ves de utilizar ModelForm y hacer las validaciones en mismo Fromulario que tienes, y realziar todo la logica en el tu vista.